# bootstrap modal box open jquery location picker does not display

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I work with jquery location picker plugin for google map. Now, I open modal and the map does not display:

[image: map display]

Here is my code :

```js
$('#somecomponent1').locationpicker({
 location: {latitude: 46.15242437752303, longitude: 2.7470703125},
 radius: 300
 });
```

```html
<a class="form-control btn" style="background-color:#FA8F13;color:white" href="#" data-target="#pwdModal1" data-toggle="modal" class="forgot-pass"> Press </a><br>

<div id="pwdModal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-toggle="modal" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">
               <div id="somecomponent1" style="height:400px;width:100%;">                                      
                  </div>
              </div>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Thanks.
DEMO : http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

use ['autosize'](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/) of locationpicker in the shown event of bootstarp modal.

```
  $('#pwdModal1").on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#somecomponent1').locationpicker('autosize');

  });
```

Comment: this was quickly changed from `google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");` after I posted `=)`

Comment: @BenG no Offence  initially I thought question was on Google map.Even I do not you have posted the answer while I am editing my answer

Answer (score 1):

it advises in the documentation in the link for the [**demo**](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/):-

> **Using widget in modal**
>
> It is pretty common situation when you put
> widget into the container which is not visible during initialization,
> e.g. modal dialog. In thins case you need to call "autosize" method
> each time you resize container.

```
$('#pwdModal1').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#somecomponent1').locationpicker('autosize');
});
```